# How and pause and resume uploads in php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, upload

Can someone give some pointers regarding implementing pause and  resume uploads using php and jquery ?

Regards,

Comment: My upload script is not so fancy .I am basically moving the data from the $_FILES  to my upload directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use html5 to do this

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/04/resumeupload/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to pause uploads with jQuery/PHP. Uploading a file relies on a POST request, which is either sent or isn't.

However, [this plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) allows you to cancel them, along with some other very nice things (all without Flash).

If you want more options, go for [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), which uses Flash.

Comment: I looked at uploadify, plupload . But we cannot seem to pause and resume uploads.Hence the question here

Comment: any other way using php and javascript ?

Comment: Not possible. You have to use Flash or Java in order to do that. By the way, Javascript is clientside and has nothing to do with file-upload

Comment: no in html5 they support file API.http://www.speich.net/articles/html5-uploader.php